# Json data-type on PG heroku . Works locally . PG::InvalidTextRepresentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, heroku

I login user using omniauth and then store some attributes in the database. Here is how I remove the blank attributes of the omniauth hash and select some attributes

```
  def update_blank_attributes(attributes,force_update_attr)
    attributes.each { |k,v| puts attributes.delete(k) unless (force_update_attr.include?(k)||read_attribute(k).blank?) }
    update_attributes!(attributes)
  end
```

My User model has a data class which is a json data type:

```
class AddDataToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :data, :json
  end
end
```

This works fine locally , even after dropping and recreating database .

However I get following error on heroku:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
 DETAIL:  Token "=" is invalid.
 CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: "linkedin_data"=...
: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "data", "email", "name", "provider", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"):
 app/models/user.rb:68:in `update_blank_attributes'
   app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:38:in `create'
 PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
 CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: "linkedin_data"=...
DETAIL:  Token "=" is invalid.


local PG version:9.3.3 
Heroku PG version: 9.3.3
```

I am getting/saving the same data from Linkedin in local as well as in heroku since its exact same call to linkedin for authentication

Answer (score 0):

What database do you use locally?  Is it a Postgres database and is it the same [version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#version-support) as that used on Heroku?  What version of Postgres are you using on Heroku?   (you can find out with something like

```
heroku pg:info -a appname
...
PG Version:  9.2.6
```

So I guess my hypothesis is that you're using different versions, and so you're not seeing the problem locally.  Either that, or you have different data in the Heroku app so you're seeing the problem manifest there.

Comment: local PG version:9.3.0
Heroku PG version: 9.3.3

Comment: Hi Jon, I updated the local database and couldnt reproduce the problem locally. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting heroku dynos fixed the issue for me